# Strange behaviour when Meteor server is built with Android platform

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm making a todo list app, using meteor and cordova full code is at: [github](https://github.com/jms301/todo-play).

I've added an Android app version. Login is via accounts-password.

The server is running via nodejs with an nginx frontend.

**The problem:**

If I build the server with the android-platform then connect an android device to it the login buttons appear briefly but then the screen refreshes and they're gone and will not return unless the app cache is cleared.

If I build the server without the android-platform then it works fine. This happens with meteor run android (emulated). meteor run android-device and via loading an APK from the play store.

I assume what is happening is building the server with android platform results in a different version of the code being put on the server which then gets pushed to the phone when it connects.

But I have no clue how to debug this.

Comment: Check if you are successfully getting connected to the ddp server.  Accounts will not work properly client side without being correctly connected to the ddp server.  Not sure off the top of my head how best to check, but the server flag may take you in the right direction to fix it.

Comment: It is definitely connecting fine originally, I see the access in the server logs. It then seems to download a new version of the app and stops working, could well be it's failing to connect to anything. I've no idea how to see what the android app is trying to do after the code updates though.